# Python Daemon Process Memory Management

Tags: python, memory, dictionary, freebsd, python-daemon

I'm currently writing a Python daemon process that monitors a log file in realtime and updates entries in a Postgresql database based on their results. The process only cares about a unique key that appears in the log file and the most recent value it's seen from that key.

I'm using a polling approach,and process a new batch every 10 seconds. In order to reduce the overall set of data to avoid extraneous updates to the database, I'm only storing the key and the most recent value in a dict. Depending on how much activity there has been in the last 10 seconds, this dict can vary from 10-1000 unique entries. Then the dict gets "processed" and those results are sent to the database.

My main concern has revolves around memory management and the dict over time (days, weeks, etc). Since this is a daemon process that's constantly running, memory usage bloats based on the size of the dict, but never shrinks appropriately. I've tried reseting dict using a standard dereference, and the dict.clear() method after processing a batch, but noticed no changes in memory usage (FreeBSD/top). It seems that forcing a gc.collect() does recover some memory, but usually only around 50%.

Do you guys have any advice on how I should proceed? Is there something more I could be doing in my process? Feel free to chime in if you see a different road around the issue :)

Comment: What Python version you are using? Python 2.5 older will retain the peak memory usage and OS never reclaims it.

Comment: I'm running Python 2.7.2

Comment: I suggest you use Heapy to debug memory leaks in your code: http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy

Comment: Does your daemon run in a while loop? if so, do you reset the dictionary like myDict = {} before or after the initiation of the while loop? if it is before, that might be why it isn't allocating memory properly. It would be useful to post some code.
Otherwise, you can try to profile your code. You could monitor the growth of your virtual and resident memory located in your /proc/"PID#"/status directory as your daemon runs. It might give some clarity as to what is growing and how it is trending. 

http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html python's cProfile is also useful

Comment: @mshell_lauren Yes, and the dict is initialized in the init and reset within the while loop. However, I've been testing in the interpreter without a while loop and am seeing no change..

Comment: Hmmm, I would really suggest memory profiling then. you can use os.getpid to find the process id and then run a check of all your memory in the /proc dir. I usually keep track of that when debugging memory leaks. Sorry, I wasn't sure, if you are creating the dict in the object, are you then creating a new object with each time the code is run, or creating one and adding to it...You say you are doing it without a loop... I am then curious as to why this it not re-allocating memory each time the code is run....you could try removing the while loop and setting the code to run with cron

Answer (score 0):

When you clear() the dict or del the objects referenced by the dict, the contained objects are still around in memory. If they aren't referenced anywhere, they can be garbage-collected, as you have seen, but garbage-collection isn't run explicitly on a del or clear().

I found this similar question for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996437/memory-management-and-python-how-much-do-you-need-to-know. In short, if you aren't running low on memory, you really don't need to worry a lot about this.  FreeBSD itself does a good job handling virtual memory, so even if you have a huge amount of stale objects in your Python program, your machine probably won't be swapping to the disk.